# Возможна ли отмена автоматического приведения к символам типа char или его синонимов?

Tags: c++, devc++

Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() 
{
    char    ch{64};
    int8_t  ich{64};

    cout << ch << endl 
        << ich << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

На выходе получаем соответственно символы:

```
T
T
```

Уверен, что int8_t, char8_t и т.д. лишь синонимы для char и отличия лишь в семантике. Так вот вопрос, возможно ли отключения автоматического приведения char и ему подобных, в идеале только int8_t и uint8_t? Неудобно все время делать static_cast() в выводах.

Comment: char = signed char;
int8_t = signed char;
uint8_t = unsigned char != signed char;
А вообще для чисел лучше использовать int по многим причинам (выравнивание, однозначность интерпретации как числа и проч.)

Comment: Но ведь сейчас в основном распространена архитектура x64 где выравнивание 8 байт. А int используется по умолчанию с давних времен. Не лучше ли тогда использовать long или int64_t?

Comment: х64, если рассматривать по существу, лишь хитрая надстройка над х32. Источник не смогу указать, вроде бы в документации AMD, утверждается, что везде, где применимо, лучше использовать 32-битные данные. Поэтому int вполне себя оправдывает.

Comment: Архитектуры x64 и x86 не требуют обязательного выравнивания данных (хотя выравнивание очень желательно для достижения максимальной производительности). Тяготение к типу int - это языковой атавизм, тянущийся еще из языка BCPL, в котором был только один тип данных. Тип для целых чисел следует выбирать в первую очередь исходя из диапазона значений, которые должны в нем храниться. А ширину регистра, в которой этот тип данных будет записываться, имеет смысл отдать на откуп компилятору. Собственно в более толковом языке ada все так и устроено.

Comment: @VTT комментарий верен только для пользовательских структур, если фактический размер не важен. Компилятор всё равно выполнить выравнивание. А вот в системных структура типа GDT, IDT и подобных или в случае когда нужно впихнуть максимум в минимум - выравнивание необходимо. В целом использование int - лучший вариант. И кода генерится меньше, и скорость выше.

Comment: @Adokenai Выравнивание структур компилятором тоже является опциональным. Как я уже писал выше, выравнивание может понадобится для достижения максимальной производительности; еще оно может понадобится при соблюдении соглашений о вызове в некоторых других ситуациях, но в целом оно является опциональным. Использование именно типа `int` стоит вообще исключить, так как он не подразумевает даже минимальной привязки к домену данных, которые должны в нем храниться (в отличие от различных библиотечных типов `uint8_t` и т.д.). И нет, "кода генерится меньше" и "скорость выше" это совсем не факт.

Comment: Можно сделать свой класс-обёртку с перегруженным оператором << или неявным приведением к целочисленному типу, если не хотите кастить каждый раз

Comment: @cppquestions классы с перегрузкой уже делал, там все отлично. Просто хотелось бы знать возможно ли изменить поведение по умолчанию ostream или саму обработку типов. Хотя бы из научного интереса)

Comment: О каком именно "приведении" идет речь? Я в упор не вижу, отключение какого "автоматичнского приведения" может поменять это поведение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В С++ типы `char` `signed char` `unsigned char` `char8_t` `char16_t` `char32_t` являются различными фундаментальными типами. В приведенном фрагменте никакого приведения типов не происходит, так как имеется перегруженный оператор << для `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char`. А неявные преобразования в языке никак не отключаются, и их не планируют устранять в обозримом будущем.

Answer (score 0):

Автоматическое приведение типа придумано давно в Си. Если вам это не нравится, НЕ пользуйтесь этими типами, а создайте свой класс, примерно такой:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic myint.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class   MyInt{
public:
int i;
explicit    MyInt(int   x):i{x}{}
};

int main() 
{
    char    ch{64};
    int8_t  ich{64};
        MyInt   mi{ch};
        MyInt   mii{ich};
    cout << ch << endl 
        << ich << endl
            <<  mi.i    <<  endl
            <<  mii.i   <<  endl    ;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод такой:

```
@
@
64
64
```

Comment: Но внутри класса он храниться как int и работается с ним как с int'ом. Соответственно память и все остальное как у int + код усложняется. Тогда есть ли смысл? Легче использовать фундаментальный тип.

Comment: Намекаю ещё раз, сделайте второй класс `MyChar` и автоматического приведения типа между вашими `int` и `char` будет просто запрещено. `explicit` - в помощь.